# Reason for casting preincrement result to void

Tags: c++

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n) gives the following code for a possible `for_each_n` implementation:

```
template<class InputIt, class Size, class UnaryFunction>
InputIt for_each_n(InputIt first, Size n, UnaryFunction f)
{
    for (Size i = 0; i < n; ++first, (void) ++i) {
        f(*first);
    }
    return first;
}
```

Why is the result of `++i` cast to `void`? Is it because we discard the result of `++i` to suppress the possible compiler warning? If so, why is the `++first` not cast to `void` as well? Because `operator ,` implicitly discards it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In

```
++first, (void) ++i
```

first, `++first` is evaluated, and then `(void) ++i` is evaluated.

When I was a C++ beginner I thought this was some special syntax that lets you perform multiple actions during the "increment" step of a for loop. However there is in fact no such special syntax. The reason why two actions can be taken here is that the comma operator is used to combine two expressions into a single expression.

Since the comma operator is overloadable, and `std::for_each_n` is a generic algorithm, there is a small chance that the user has defined an overloaded comma operator whose first argument is the `InputIt` type. This isn't particularly likely, but it is possible. So, in order to guarantee that we simply do `++first` and then `++i`, with no other side effects, it's necessary to force the built-in comma operator to be used. This is done by casting one of the arguments to `void`: you cannot have a `void` argument to `operator,` (or any other function) so this prevents any user-defined overloads from being called.

Comment: libc++ has `++__first, --__n`. Is this technically broken for custom iterators that overloads `operator,(It, std::size_t)`?

Comment: @eerorika I don't see a for loop [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L896)

Comment: Sorry, I misread. the code is from libstdc++ instead: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d9375e490072d1aae73a93949aa158fcd2a27018/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/pstl/algorithm_impl.h#L82

Comment: @eerorika It could be a bug. I don't know. Maybe open a bug report?

Comment: @Brian Did you open the bug report? Is it online somewhere?